# Custom Controller Action to Anchor tag

Tags: mvc

Any ideas on how to determine the route of the controller from Anchor Tag?

For Example:

Question 1: When Product Name link in screen 1 is clicked.The product details from the controller have to be displayed.How to send the custom action to href in the anchor tag?

Question 2: How to pass the data source from the screen 1 to the controller?

Comment: I presume you have a Model of your items/products? You need to post it up as well as some skeleton code which you are using (I assume you have a foreach loop of some sort) - it'll making trying to help you easier than guessing what you are doing.

Comment: You can pass the id of product to description page and get the id in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by retrieving URL of from Route Name. example could be:

```
@{ var prodID = 123; } <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("vinc",new { id = prodID })">routinglink</a>
```

where id will be your product id or Sitecore Item id which you will use in Controller Action method as a parameter.

You will create such route in your custom routing logic [reference](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/700677)